# Build a checkbox list in razor page from many-to-many EF Core entity

Tags: c#, razor-pages, ef-core-2.2

My question is: How to build html markup in razor pages and the LINQ queries (in the backend) to bring a checkbox list of all my SubCategoies in the EDIT and CREATE views.

Allowing me to create a product with multiple subcategories and also updating them at any time in the EDIT view.

Using .Net EF Core 2.2, Razor Pages.

Main class (Product):

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public List<ProductSubcategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

}
```

Product has a many-to-many relationship with Subcategory:

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductSubcategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

So the join table (entity) is ProductSubcategory:

```
 public class ProductSubcategory
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

The Edit (and create) Product view:

```
 <h2>Editar: @Model.Product.Name</h2>


<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Product.Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Description"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>


        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Product.Description"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Category"></label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Category" asp-items="Model.Categories"></select>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Product.Category"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        //Code to allow the subcategory selection.
        //preferable as checkboxes 

        //() subcat1    (x)subcat2    ()subcat3
        //() subcat4    ()subcat5    (x)subcat6

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

The Edit.cshtml.cs PageModel

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IProductData _ProductData;
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _HtmlHelper;
    [BindProperty]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public string MessageCreate { get; set; }


    public EditModel(IProductData _productData, IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper)
    {
        _ProductData = _productData;
        _HtmlHelper = _htmlHelper;
    }


    public IActionResult OnGet(int? productId)
    {
        Categories = _HtmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList<Category>();

        if (productId.HasValue)
        {
            Product = _ProductData.GetById(productId.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageCreate = "Criar novo Produto";
            Product = new Product();
        }

        if (Product == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./NotFound");
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Categories = _HtmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList<Category>();
            return Page();
        }

        if (Product.Id > 0)
        {
            _ProductData.Update(Product);
        }
        else
        {
            _ProductData.Create(Product);
        }

        _ProductData.Commit();

        TempData["Message"] = "Produto salvo!!!";

        //PRG POST-REDIRECT-GET
        return RedirectToPage("./Detail", new { productId = Product.Id });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is used to represent a boolean property. I see you don't have a bool property so I suppose you need to add a Boolean property in `SubCategories` class like:

```
public bool IsChecked { get; set; } // added this property
```

Then you need to add a property to your PageModel(Edit or Create) to represent the data and ensured that posted values will be bound to it:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Subcategory> SubCategories { get; set; } = new List<Subcategory>();
```

At the end all you need is to get the model binder to associate each checkbox with a specific Subcategory. The following code shows my example in .cshtml file:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubCategories.Count(); i++)
 {
    <input asp-for="SubCategories[i].IsChecked" />
 }
```

Comment: Its kind of work, i mean, i can see the number os subcategories as checkboxes but without a label Name for then. How do i extract the name of the subcategories? I tried to use foreach(var item in SubCategories) but i cannot use "item.Name"

Comment: The name in your Subcategories is just one string so if you extract it inside the for loop dhe result will be the same string name in all checkbox. I'm not sure but maybe you can create an enum and the value of it extract it as names of checkbox.